# Wait for batch file to finish process in Powershell before executing other commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to execute a Powershell file which needs to execute batch file and once batch file processing completes then only proceed to next command And, batch process shouldn't open a new window.

```
$p = Start-Process $dir\bin\stop.bat -Wait -Passthru
$p.WaitForExit()
if ($p.ExitCode -eq 0) {
      java "-Dtar.memoryMapped=true" -Xms8g -Xmx8g -jar oak-run-1.4.6.jar checkpoints $dir\repository\segmentstore | Out-File $log_path\log_checkpoints.txt }
```

I tried above code but it's not working.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it's not working". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Once the bat file process completes then only next command should be executed. But, it's executing even before batch process completes resulting in unsuccess of 2nd command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to wait for the batch file to finish (in the same window):

```
start $dir\bin\stop.bat -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Can you be more specific if it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`Start-Process` is pretty straightforward with `-Wait` and `-NoNewWindow` parameters doing what you expect. Use the `-PassThru' only to acquire an object that you need to query afterwards.

FYI `& path 2>&1` would also wait for the execution with the necessary error stream redirection to the console.